# How does one stop Overleaf from automatically compiling the source code?

Tags: compiling, overleaf

[image: Source Code on Overleaf]

The attached photo is a screenshot of my source code in Overleaf.

How can I get Overleaf to leave my code as *just* code, without automatically compiling it in the source? (I am fine with the compilation on the PDF side, obviously.) It is really annoying especially because it messes up the cursor when I try to backspace, etc. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: there is a drop-down menu if you click on the little triangle on the `Recompile` button...

Comment: Yes, I have put auto-compile off for a while now; but this still happens. It does not automatically compile on the PDF side, but it does automatically compile on the code side...

Comment: Do you mean that it stops showing it as `Rich Text`? Then click on `Source` above your code.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ If you're already in Source mode and this happens: you most likely have a browser plugin that's doing this (e.g. [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-all-the-things/cbimabofgmfdkicghcadidpemeenbffn)); so try disabling your browser plugins.

Comment: @LianTzeLim : Thank you, I do indeed have that browser plug-in. This could very well be it; I might just use Overleaf on Safari then. Thanks!

Comment: @TivV : It's already on Source.